# Get 1D array index from a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, math, 2d

Is there a way to get the array index of a 1D array from a 2D array?

For Eg: I have a 2D array, the array size is unknown and changes (I've used std::vector) to push_back as and when required. This works fine as long as its a 2D array but I need to get the 1D array index of this 2D array.

```
2D array:
Group 1 - 1, 2, 3
Group 2 - 4, 5, 6
Group 3 - 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

and so on.

So, basically is there a quick way to know that when 6 is selected from Group 2 i.e. Array[1][2] = 6 => I need the array index as: 1D array=> Array[5] = 6 => i.e. I need 5 as my answer. I have tried several things but no luck so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: Was the sum of the sizes of all previous groups plus the index in the current group among the things you tried?

Comment: If you are using C++ don't use raw arrays to store matrcies. Use an ADT matrix type (like those provied by Linear algebra libraries) and call their .data() member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is static, you can make another array in which you will store the offset for each 1D array. For your example, you will have the following array `offset = {0, 3, 6}`. Then you can find the index by `offset[row] + col`.

If you can change the row sizes, then you can store the size of each row in a Binary indexed tree and find the offset in O(log n) with a single query, where n is the amount of rows (1D vectors). However, each time you change the row size, you would have to update the structure again in O(log n).

Comment: offset technically would be the .size() parameter of std::vector wouldn't it for each group?

Comment: @TheNewbie Yes, the accumulated .size() parameters of each group. (as offset will be an array)

Comment: Your answer looks very promising but I am still trying to get the offset. Any suggestions on how do I get that? The .size() just gives me the current size of the Group.

Comment: @TheNewbie I guess something like (assuming group is implemented as vector< vector<int> > and offset is an regular array of ints): `offset[0] = 0; for (int row=0; row < (int)group.size; ++row) offset[row+1] = offset[row] + (int)group[row].size();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a vector of vectors (or a list of vectors), the memory locations are not guaranteed to be related.  So to make it behave like a 1-dimensional array, you would need to wrap the container in your own class and overload `operator[]`.  That operator would then need to check the index to determine the proper vector element to return.  A simplified version might look like:

```
T& operator[](std::size_t index)
{
    std::size_t temp = index;
    if (index < myVectors[0].size())
    {
        return myVectors[0][index];
    }

    temp = index - myVectors[0].size()
    if (temp < myVectors[1].size())
    {
        return myVectors[1][temp];
    }

    // etc ...
}
```

You can simplify it to a loop:

```
T& operator[](std::size_t index)
{
    std::size_t temp = index;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < myVectors.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (temp < myVectors[i].size())
        {
            return myVectors[i][temp];
        }
        temp -= myVectors[i].size();
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("Array access out of bounds!");
}
```